# AWS S3 File Upload causes `403 Forbidden` response: AccessDenied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is my code

```
<?php
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

error_reporting(0);

function pre($arr){
    echo '<pre>';print_r($arr);echo '</pre>';
}

if($_FILES['image']['name'] != ''){

require 'aws/aws-autoloader.php';

$client = S3Client::factory([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'eu-west-2',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => "XXXXXXX",
        'secret' => "XXXXXXX"
    ],
    'scheme' => 'http'
 ]);
try {
    $insert = $client->putObject([
        'Bucket'     =>'xxx',
        'Key'        => $_FILES["image"]["name"],
        'SourceFile' => $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],
        'ACL'        => 'public-read'
    ]);
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    // Catch an S3 specific exception.
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
die;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="aws.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

When I try to upload an image, I get this error

> Error executing "PutObject" on "http://xxx.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/b_browse.png"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `PUT http://xxx.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/b_browse.png` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response: AccessDeniedAccess Denied07E90B (truncated...) AccessDenied (client): Access Denied - AccessDeniedAccess Denied07E90B12D3A0DBA15kSo11cfv57kBQ3sBo9dHHtZb4Xt566KS64btFHyKg6a0cIxRQWiprSAK3Tu4I+XCIyBNU3Dics=

Any ideas on what might be the issue? I have given FullS3Permission to the user as well.

Comment: Maybe you can share the CORS settings of your bucket.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: This [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-cors-configuration.html) shows the steps to reach it via the console.